# Removing constants out of square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation $$ z = \dfrac{ħ}{\sqrt{2m_e T k_B \ln 2}} $$

Where $2, \hbar, m_e ,  k_B , \ln(2) $ are constants. What I want to do is turn this equation into the form $$ z = k_1 * \text{something} $$ where $k_1$ are all the constants and $\text{something}$ is an expression which only has the only variable $T$. My idea was: $$ k_1 * \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{T}}$$ with $k_1 = \dfrac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m_ek_b\ln2}}$

Is this correct? Are there perhaps even more "aesthetic" versions?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: See, this is why physics is annoying. You are constantly burdened with a load of uninteresting constants denoted by unneccessarily complicated letters.

Comment: ..and then they tell you: "but we cannot be sure what's going on since little things do as they please", @TooOldForMath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct...as long as either you work with complex functions or the signs of things are such that the square roots are defined.

For example, in your case it **must** be the varable $\;T\;$ is positive, otherwise $\;\sqrt T\;$ isn't defined in the reals...but since this seems to be quantum mechanics, with the reduced Planck constant, the electron mass and etc., it looks like things are positive and thus you're cool.

Remember: $\;\sqrt1=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}\color{red}\neq\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\;$ , even in the complex...

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for the stupid question, but I needed to be 1 million percent sure!